# Can Microsoft Cognitive Services analyze Microsoft Office documents?

Tags: text-analytics-api

I'd like to do a key phrase analysis of a Microsoft Word document. It looks like the API only takes JSON documents. Is there a route to use real life documents like Microsoft Office documents?

Comment: Could you pls explain which API you are planning use/what is the scenario/usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent hackathon project, [Resolving Managed Metadata Madness in SharePoint](https://devpost.com/software/resolving-managed-metadata-madness-in-sharepoint), answers this question.

The developer of that project used a three step process involving custom code. An Azure Function was written to extract the text to pass to the API. The function returns the results of the analysis back to Microsoft Flow.

1. A Flow attached to Document Library will call the Azure Function
   that’ll do the heavy lifting
2. An Azure Function will run, extract
   text, analyze it using Azure Cognitive Services, and then write the
   info back to SharePoint Online
3. Finally, notifies admin of the
   execution and the creator of the file.